# Complete sets of pictures by replacing blanks

Tags: pattern, visual, geometry, progressive-matrix

I made a couple of new ones. I liked making the first one the most. The first one seems to be the easiest for me but I can see someone getting stuck on it if they don't figure out the idea. The second one is similar to the last one. Some people will probably get those really fast. (Will share my solution in a couple of days or weeks. I think I gave it away too quickly last time.)

[image: Shapes, Inductive reasoning]

[image: Shapes, Arrangement, Permutation]

[image: Shapes, Permutations, Groupings]

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

> Problem 2, answer 1:
>  All purple circles are tangential and have one single intersection point (same tangent point for all circles). Blue circle if any does not intersect them at all. This is the case of answer 1. Answer 2/3/4 are discarded because there is not a single intersection point for all purple circles

> Problem 3, answer 1:
>  Purple circle are tangential. When little spot is blue, then black circle crosses the tangential point. if orange, then black circle simply has its center aligned with 2 purple circles centers. For answer 2/3, bad center for black circle. For answer 4, bad intersection of black circle (should cross purple tangential point)

Comment: Your 2. answer is correct.
The 3. answer is very close in your reasoning but the position of the centers has nothing to do with the solution. They don't quite allign when you look closely.